# Getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined" while form submitting in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express

I want to store html form data in JSON file But getting error.

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined"

And also tell me how to create json file from string JSON. And how to add data from multiple users.

My html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign up</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        background-color: rgb(66, 244, 229);
        padding: 15px;
        margin: auto;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
    input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: none;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: orange;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="/form" method="Post">
        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter your Name"><br> 
 <br>
        <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter Email id"><br> 
 <br>
        <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Set Password"> 
   <br><br>
        <input type="number" name="Mobile" placeholder="Enter mobile 
  number"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Server.js file is:

```
var express= require('express');

var app= express();

app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

app.all('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile('/express.js/public/signup.html');
});

app.post("/form", function(req, res){
    var username= req.body.Name;
    var email= req.body.Email;
    var mobile= req.body.Mobile;
    var password= req.body.Password;

    var object= { name_new:username, mail: email, pass_word:password, 
     Mobile_No: mobile}
    var json= JSON.stringify(obj);
   });

app.listen(1111);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What happens when you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` before your `var username= req.body.Name;` ?

Comment: install body-parser and add  `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));` after `var app= express();`

Comment: It is showing Undefined.

Comment: Still showing undefined @WTFtom

Answer (score 1):

you have to parse your request with body-parser packages

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

include body-parser on routes

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Now you will able to get all post data inside routes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a body parser to be able to use `req.body` in a post route:

```js
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app= express();

// parse forms with MIME type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 

app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

app.all('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile('/express.js/public/signup.html');
});

app.post("/form", function(req, res){
    var username= req.body.Name;
    var email= req.body.Email;
    var mobile= req.body.Mobile;
    var password= req.body.Password;

    var object= { name_new:username, mail: email, pass_word:password, 
     Mobile_No: mobile}
    var json= JSON.stringify(obj);
   });

app.listen(1111);
```

From the [documentation of body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

> ### bodyParser.urlencoded([options])
>
> Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies and only looks at requests where the `Content-Type` header matches the `type` option. This parser accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.
>
> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. `req.body`). This object will contain key-value pairs, where the value can be a string or array (when extended is `false`), or any type (when extended is `true`).

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the manual of expressjs. You need a body-parsing middleware

> req.body
>   Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body